# jupyter run magic pass arguments to notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When you are in a first jupyter notebook (first.ipynb) you can execute a second one, but how can arguments be passed along?

Assuming the second one has the following contents:

```
xx = 10
```

You can call the second one from the first one like:

```
%run second.ipynb
xx # will print 10 (= nicely set up from the second one)
```

But how can I pass a parameter to the second notebook / to the run magic?
Ie.

```
%run second.ipynb foo=20
```

And then have a:

```
if foo is not None:

    xx = foo
```

in the second one?

This naive approach fails with:

```
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

i.e. the parameter is not passed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is executing in the same process - I can simply define the arguments as variables in the first notebook.

It feels dirty - but comes handy.