# Unable to reference a excel marco file while running a juypter-notebook from another notebook

Tags: python, excel, vba, jupyter-notebook

I'm trying to run a jupyter notebook file called `Seg_pivot.ipynb` from `main.ipynb`. The main.ipynb has one line of code: `%run "fi/Seg_pivot.ipynb"`

The current directory structure looks like the following: [image]

The `Seg_pivot.ipynb` runs a module in the MyMacro, used to style the files in the result folder. When I run the `Seg_pivot.ipynb` everything works. But when I run the `main.ipynb`, it gives a **FileNotFound error: No such file: 'mymacro.xlsm'**

In the `Seg_pivot.ipynb` this is how I call the macro:

```
import xlwings as xw
wb = xw.Book("MyMacro.xlsm")
s_macro = wb.macro("Module2.styleF")
s_macro()
```

Comment: Are you setting the working directory inside `Seg_pivot.ipynb` using the magic command `%cd` so that it works in both places? Without seeing more code, I'd guess you are running `Seg_pivot.ipynb` as itself and seeing it work because the working directory then is alongside `Seg_pivot.ipynb` so the running code sees the macro as that is with it. When you run it from `main.ipynb`, the directory where  `main.ipynb` resides is the working directory by default. The macro isn't there.

Comment: No, I'm not using that magic command. Can you show me how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think putting inside your notebook `Seg_pivot.ipynb` near the top, the following may help:

```py
import pathlib
%cd {pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()}
```

That will always set the working directory to where `Seg_pivot.ipynb` is in your file hierarchy when it runs.

Getting he path to the notebook file something is running it is based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3430395/8508004). The magic `%cd` command is documented [here](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-cd).

In your case, you may wish to reset the current working directory back in `main.ipynb`, too,  i.e., after it runs the `Seg_pivot.ipynb` notebook if `main.ipynb` involves any paths after that.

Comment: And it still allows `Seg_pivot.ipynb` to work when you run it directly? I was using a simple test but just was wondering if there was more complexity.

Comment: It is working somehow, I get an output saying: ```[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified; '{pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()}'```

Comment: Oh so, it still works **both ways** but you just need to ignore that? Probably easier to just leave it then unless you are doing some fancy produciton thing? I think the cd fails when you run `Seg_pivot.ipynb` directly, but because current working directory will be already correct, not an issue. We could add a conditional but probably easier just to ignore the error if it continues running.

Comment: After I run the ```main.ipynb``` code, it sets the working directory to the 'fi' folder where the ```Seg_pivot.ipynb``` file is stored. How to return to the directory where the ```main.ipynb``` stored once ```Seg_pivot.ipynb``` is executed?

Comment: I tried adding the following at the end of the ```Seg_pivot.ipynb``` script: ```%cd {pathlib.Path(__file__).parent}``` . Refrence: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218802/get-parent-of-current-directory-from-python-script

Comment: Adding the following at the end of the ```Seg_pivot.ipynb``` script works: ```%cd  {pathlib.Path().resolve().parent}``` . Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30218802/get-parent-of-current-directory-from-python-script

Comment: Yes, your last three comments refer to why I said, "In your case, you may wish to reset the current working directory back in `main.ipynb`, too".  I would suggest it makes more sense to be a step in `main.ipynb` after it runs the other notebook from `main.ipynb`. But if it works in `Seg_pivot.ipynb`, that is fine. As long as a few months from now, you can tell how to run both notebooks clearly, it shouldn't be a big deal. There's other ways to do it that would be more thorough, such as add a flag that you send to `Seg_pivot.ipynb` when calling it from `main.ipynb`, and act aprropriately.

Comment: <continued> Alternatively, if what `Seg_pivot.ipynb` does could be better modularized, there's ways restructure it to import it using [importnb](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez). Or restructure the main things it does to a script that both `main.ipynb` and `Seg_pivot.ipyn` can use. The main point is that now you see what the original issue was and that there's ways to address it.

Comment: Extending on the above. I wanted to pass/import a string variable from the parent notebook ```main.ipynb``` to the child notebook ```Seg_pivot.ipynb```. How to do that?

Comment: If I recall correctly, when you execute `%run "fi/Seg_pivot.ipynb"` in `main.ipynb`, it is running the notebook in the namespace of `main.ipynb`. I think I'm right and in fact that is why the `%cd` was needed. (When running scripts you actually need the specific `-i` flag for `interactively` to run the script in the current namespace instead of an empty one.) So when you execute that run command to run `Seg_pivot.ipynb` anything you already defined earlier in `main.ipynb` is useable by `Seg_pivot.ipynb`. You can easily test this separately from your complex notebooks by making two really ....

Comment: <continued> simple ones that parallel yours and test if you can print a variable define from in the invoking one in the one you call with `%run`. So the hard part is already handled. But how do you keep `Seg_pivot.ipynb` working alone becomes the question, right? Because if I recall you also like to be able to run `Seg_pivot.ipynb` separately on its own? So inside of `Seg_pivot.ipynb` you put a `try ... except` block where you check if the variable you'll sometimes be passing in from `main` is of the type you expect it to be and you set the `except` to set a default dummy value if there's a...

Comment: <continued> `NameError`. For example, set the variable to a strange string, like "iDIDnotComeFromMAiN". And you add an `if`conditional in `Seg_pivot.ipynb` to do the thing it should do when it gets something from `main`. Specifically, the pseudocode would be something like `if <variable> != "iDIDnotComeFromMAiN", then do the thing it should do when passed in and either handle everything else with an `else` clause or just don't have anything else besides the thing to do when it comes from `main.ipynb`. If it was only one thing to do, you can build the entire thing in the `try...except`.   ...

Comment: <continued> Setting a flag using the `try .. except` is just easier, can be made to be more explicit as to what is happening, and gives you more flexibility to do something different again later in the notebook, depending on whether the variable is passed in or not from `main.ipynb`

Comment: What I said in my first comment about passing things is the long way of saying [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64697171/8508004). And there are other ways if you had more complexity involved, such as [this](https://felixchenier.uqam.ca/a-better-way-to-run-a-jupyter-notebook-with-arguments/) or use [Parpermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill#) to execute the other notebook from `main.ipynb`. In fact, because Papermill allows you to set a default and then overwrite it when injecting, it is a more civilized way to handle what I was getting at with the `try..except` in `Seg_pivot`.

Comment: Thanks, Wayne. This has been very helpful!

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75803877/8508004) may be helpful, too.